# When comment is upvoted, can this be in notification?

Tags: feature-request, comments

When my comment has an upvote, can this be shown in my notification?

Comment: no. but you can every once and a while you can use the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/307803/my-most-upvoted-comments-including-comment-text) to see all your UVed comments. (note that there is a delay of about a week for the data there)